# Convert AWS private key from .pem format to .der format for use with java

Tags: openssl, amazon-cloudfront, pem, cfml, aws-java-sdk

Using CFML (Lucee), I'm trying to use the AWS java SDK (v1.11) to create signed Cloudfront URLs and I'm stuck trying to create the signature. The problem is that I cannot seem to convert my .pem private key to .der format. I keep getting various invalid key errors on the last line of the following code snippet:

```
    var derContent = FileReadBinary("C:/path/to/cert.der");
    var keySpec = createObject("java", "java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec");
    var keyFactory = createObject("java", "java.security.KeyFactory").getInstance("RSA");
    var privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec.init(derContent));
```

I've tried several attempts to convert the file using openssl, but I get various problems.

**This command will not create the .pem certificate:**

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -outform DER -text -in pk-XXXX.pem -out pk-XXXX.der

unable to load certificate
30276:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../openssl- 
1.1.1a/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

**This one creates the cert, but I get an `invalid key format` error calling `generatePrivate()`**

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -outform DER -text -in pk-XXXX.pem -out pk-XXXX.der
```

Can anyone suggest other methods to convert the certificate? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CFPrivateDistJavaDevelopment.html

This openssl command will convert your cloudfront private key file into .der format:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in aws-private-key.pem -inform PEM -out aws-private-key.der -outform DER
```